# How can a isometric floor be drawn on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

So so far I have the following code. It draws a row of isometric tiles on a HTML5 canvas. However, I would like to create an entire floor and not just a single row, and despite all my attempts, I've failed.

```
function createEmptyMapRow(x, r /* The offset in tiles. Setting this to 1 draws one row down. */)
{
    var cx = 0, lx = 0, ly = 0;
    while(cx != x)
    {
        renderImage(lx - (r * 32), ly + (r * 14), 'tile.png');
        lx = lx + 32;
        ly = ly + 14;
        cx++;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to write code, just give me some logic.

I'd like to be able to create a function that places tiles left to right for every row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a good resource about isometric tiles on **[this site](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-isometric-worlds-a-primer-for-game-developers--gamedev-6511)**.

Essentially you need to map points in isometric, to cartesian (which is the normal screen coordinates), and vice-versa (if you want to map user input to your isometric grid)

But building on what you have, somehow this seems to work

```
var c = cs.getContext("2d")
//size of grid is 2:1
var gridWidth=128
var gridHeight=64

//sprite could be taller
var spriteWidth=gridWidth
var spriteHeight=img.height/img.width*gridWidth

//always resize canvas with javascript. using CSS will make it stretch
cs.width = window.innerWidth    //ie8>= doesn't have innerWidth/Height
cs.height = window.innerHeight  //but they don't have canvas
var ox = cs.width/2-spriteWidth/2
var oy = spriteHeight

function renderImage(x, y) {
   c.drawImage(img, ox + (x - y) * spriteWidth/2, oy + (y + x) * gridHeight/2-(spriteHeight-gridHeight),spriteWidth,spriteHeight)
}

for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
for(var y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    renderImage(x,y)
}}
```

**[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pSHX/2/)**

Comment: This works almost perfectly well, but there are random lines between the tiles, which I also got when trying to do this.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/esispqruiwqqbbi/Screenshot%202014-05-13%2019.37.06.png

Comment: Also, how could I make the tiles a set size and not resize with the screen (I made the canvas 100% wide and high)? @mfirdaus

Comment: I think I forgot to take into account that the image can be taller than the grid. So the code now takes that into account. Also always resize canvas with javascript, and in pixels. This means, you have to use window.innerWidth/Height, to set it. You also need to change the width it on window resize + you need to redraw on canvas resize as canvas is cleared when resized. The new jsfiddle should have example of that.